# Google Workspace: Add all users in a child organization unit to a group using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-admin-sdk, google-workspace

I'd like to add all users in a child Organization Unit to a group. I can do that in Admin Dashboard but it only shows 50 users at a time. Since we have thousands of users in each child OU, this process would be inconvenience.

My solution:
I followed a guide ([Source](https://xfanatical.com/blog/add-all-ou-users-to-groups-in-google-workspace/)) and used Google Apps Script to run the following code but it simply didn't do anything. The log shows "Execution started" then "Execution completed" but no user is moved to the group. I suspect the format for the OU in the code is wrong. It is a bit tricky to get it right especially the OU is Arabic (Right to Left). Any idea what could be wrong?

```
function myFunction() {
      /**
 * Add all users of an organizational unit (OU) to specific groups
 * in Google Workspace
 * 
 * Usage:
 * Change the OU variable, in a format of /OU/SubOU/SubSubOU. The root OU is represented as /
 * Change the groupEmails variable, which is a list of group emails.
 * 
 * © 2021 xFanatical, Inc.
 * @license MIT
 *
 * @since 1.0.0 proof of concept
 */
const OU = '/كلية الطب/الطلبة/طلبة الدراسات الاولية 2019 - 2020/testing'
const groupEmails = ['100gb.limit@uokufa.edu.iq']

function addAllOUUsersToGroup() {
  let pageToken
  let page
  do {
    page = AdminDirectory.Users.list({
      customer: 'my_customer',
      maxResults: 100,
      pageToken,
      query: `orgUnitPath='${OU}'`,
    })
    let users = page.users
    if (users) {
      users.forEach((user) => {
        groupEmails.forEach((groupEmail) => {
          try {
            AdminDirectory.Members.insert({
              email: user.primaryEmail,
              role: 'MEMBER',
              type: 'USER',
            }, groupEmail)
            Logger.log(`Added user [${user.primaryEmail}] to group [${groupEmail}]`)
          } catch (e) {
            Logger.log(`Failed to add user [${user.primaryEmail}] to group [${groupEmail}], error: ${e.details && e.details.message && e.details.message}`)
          }
        })
      })
    } else {
      Logger.log('No users found.')
    }
    pageToken = page.nextPageToken
  } while (pageToken)
}
}
```

Comment: Have you checked whether any user is getting listed? Most probably it is not finding any user on that OU. I would be tempted to say the API isn't finding that OU, but I think an exception would be thrown if that were the case. Can you double-check whether there's a user in that OU, and log `page` (e.g. `Logger.log(page)`) to see the API response?

Comment: @lamblichus,
No user is getting listed after executing the function. I've tried with multiple OUs all of them have many users, still nothing. However I noticed that even if I type random OU still not getting any notice other than "Execution started" then "Execution complete". It seems that it is not reading the OU line for some odd reason.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. If I query an unexisting OU, the call fails with error `Invalid Input: INVALID_OU_ID`. If you query an existing OU that doesn't include arabic characters, do you get the same behavior?

Comment: @lamblichus, Yes I've used existing and non-existing English written OUs but I keep getting the same result. Again no error messages. I bet that there is one of those dumb mistakes somewhere in the code but I don't seem to realize exactly where!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issue:

You are not executing the function `addAllOUUsersToGroup`.

`addAllOUUsersToGroup` is declared inside `myFunction`, but it is never called. Therefore, if you execute `myFunction`, `addAllOUUsersToGroup` won't run.

#### Solution:

Either call `addAllOUUsersToGroup` inside `myFunction`. For example:

```
function myFunction() {
  // ...stuff...
  function addAllOUUsersToGroup() {
    // ...stuff...
  }
  addAllOUUsersToGroup(); // <== ADD THIS
}
```

Or, alternatively, take the function `addAllOUUsersToGroup` outside `myFunction` and call it directly:

```
function addAllOUUsersToGroup() { <== THIS IS NOT INSIDE myFunction
  // ...stuff...
}
```

#### Reference:

- [Calling functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#calling_functions)

Comment: Thank you so much! Instantly worked without drama.